# STRIPE on FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, flutter, applepay, google-pay

I have install and use FLUTTER_STRIPE, but there is a error that which I can't understand..

When I debug, click PAY and there is a error messager

```
I/flutter (32337): eccezione'package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart': Failed assertion: line 488 pos 9: '!(paymentSheetParameters.applePay != null &&

I/flutter (32337):             instance._merchantIdentifier == null)': merchantIdentifier must be specified if you are using Apple Pay. Please refer to this article to get a merchant identifier: https://support.stripe.com/questions/enable-apple-pay-on-your-stripe-account
```

If on my stripe is deactivated APPLE PAY, is activated only GOOGLE PAY...
Is it not possible to take the test without using Apple Pay?

Function with STRIPE payment

Comment: You will probably have to remove paymentSheetParameters, can you share the code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding Stripe.merchantidentifier in your main.dart file

Comment: AH ok....I try but don't possibile remove Apple Pay if I don't use this type of pay?